# Haskell, Generic method of creating Html forms

Tags: haskell, generics, servant

I am building a site in Servant, and was wondering if it wouldn't be possible to create a Generic instance for generating input fields.

What I want, is to have a

```
class ToInputField a where
    toInputField :: a -> InputField
```

Such that, an example implementation could be

```
instance ToInputField Text where
    toInputField t = InputField { type = InputText, value = t, name = "some name which I would like to be derived" }
```

Now, if every accessor function of a type, implemented this class, I would like to do something like ToJSON.

```
instance ToJSON Person
```

But instead do

```
class ToForm a where
    toForm :: a -> [InputField]

instance ToForm Person
```

But instead have something like `toInputField :: Text -> a -> InputField`, where Text is the name of the accessor field. So `toInputField` can be implemented like this

```
instance ToInputField Text where
    toInputField n t = InputField { type = InputText, value = t, name = n }
```

I have a feeling that this is possible with Generics, but I have zero experience creating a Generic implementation. Furthermore, I think it should be possible to create a Generic implementation for

```
class NamedFunctor a where
    nfmap :: (Text -> b -> c) -> [c]
```

Where Text is the name of the accessor field. Such that I can create a form by simple

```
data Person = Person { pname :: Text, pheight :: Int } deriving (Generic, NamedFunctor)    

toForm :: NamedFunctor a => a -> [InputField]
toForm = nfmap toInputField
```

Such that I can call it with

```
show . toForm $ User "testName" 172
```

And get

```
"[ InputField { type = InputText, value = "testName", name = "pname" }
 , InputField { type = InputNumber, value = "172", name = "pheight" }]"
```

The reason I ask this more generalized question, is that I don't know how I would implement any of these, neither the simple or generalized one, but I hope something like the generalized has already been implemented, since this seems really useful, and could be used to implement all kinds of things, where the names of fields are relevant, like any serialization.